# CSS for label printer

Tags: php, html, css, printing

My label sheets are 1 1/3" x 4" they are from  PRES-a-ply™ Address Labels [image]. There are 2 columns and each columns have 7 rows so basically 2x7 (labels). I am using PHP to get the addresses from my database and want to print them. I modified the first page with Bootstrap

```
<div class="container ms-5 smaller-font mt-4 text-nowrap">(label content goes here) </div>
```

php part:

```
foreach ($table_dt as $count => $data) {

    if ($count % 2 == 0) {
        echo '<div class="row gx-5">';
    }
    if ($mode === "status") {
        $address = $data['address'];
        $subject = $data['name'];
    } elseif ($mode === "cont_lbl") {
        $address = $data['address'];
        $subject = $data['contractor'];
    }
    $formated_address = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $address);
    echo '<div class="col-md-6 mb-4"><p>' . $subject . '<br>' . $formated_address . '</p></div>';

    if ($count % 2 != 0 || $count == array_key_last($table_dt)) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

And this works great for the first page. However, everything is messed up on the second page because the margins and paddings aren't good. I tried to replicate the first page so that all printed pages have the same settings in my `@media print {}` css file with these settings but I'm still not able to get it right.

```
.smaller-font{
  font-size: 11pt !important;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.ms-5 {
  margin-left: 3rem !important;
}

.mt-4 {
  margin-top: 1.5rem !important;
}
```

I also tried to just adjust the body only like this in my print.css file:

```
.smaller-font{
font-size: 11pt !important;
}

body {
margin-top: 20mm !important; 
margin-bottom: 20mm !important; 
}
```

However, it is still not giving me the proper results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that the 1st page is fit and correct, then you may use the following trick:

a) Add a CSS class for `page break`

```
<style>.break { page-break-before: always; }</style>
```

Then, at the end of each page, put the following `page break` code (but make sure that every page is using exactly the same style as the 1st page):

```
&nbsp;<h1 class="break">&nbsp;</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the issue for me is that I don't define the new pages. You could say `$table_dt` has 38 addresses, based on how the first page is formatted, 14 addresses from `$table_dt`goes on the first page 7 on left 7 on right.  The next page is automatically populated but it has 15 addresses while it's supposed to have only 14 and the margins are all messed up. I'm not sure how to define a page

Comment: Since you said the 1st page is ok, please view the source of the 1st page you have generated and use it as the format to define a page, and separate adjacent pages by the break class